# Using firestore.Timestamp.now() in Angular unit test

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am developing an Angular application, with angularfire2 `5.0.0-rc.10`. I really hope I don't mess up any terms in the following, but here we go.

I have converted Date's, to the new firestore Timestamp type. This gives me a problem when writing tests. I can only do the following:

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
it ('should create', () => {
   firestore.Timestamp.now();
});
```

If I initialize firebase in my TestBed module with:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
```

Otherwise I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Timestamp' of undefined
```

So my questions:

1. Is this intended behaviour?
2. Are you not supposed to be able to create a firstore Timestamp data type, outside of an firebase angular project?
3. Why is `firestore undefined` when imported without the initializeApp?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The `firestore.Timestamp.now()` syntax does not look familiar to me. Can you show where you got that from?

Comment: Just from the firebase repo? Here is a link https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/1608edb5f1b8d3dae342727b4914e3edc8b5dcd8/packages/firestore/src/api/timestamp.ts

Comment: The only one I see in there is just a wrapper for `Date.now()`, which is standard JavaScript: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/1608edb5f1b8d3dae342727b4914e3edc8b5dcd8/packages/firestore/src/api/timestamp.ts#L22. I'm not sure if/how that is exposed in the public API though. How about simply using `Date.now()` directly in your code.

Comment: Yes it is only a wrapper - but I am interested in the Timestamp object, `Timestamp.now()` was just an example. I am also interested in `Timestamp.fromDate()` for example :)

Comment: What version of Firebase are you using? If 5.0+ have you tried `import { firestore } from 'firebase/firestore'`

Comment: Yes - I am using 5.0+. When I try to import from `import {} from 'firebase/firestore'` I have no options?

Comment: did you try `import  'firebase/firestore'`? I know this post may be old

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it below

angular version is 11.1.2

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
```